# Creating matrix in python with pandas and numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix

I am facing the problem to creating a matrix in python which divides but instead it multiplies.

I have two dataframes:
`df_in = pd.DataFrame([[77.279999], [80.099998]], index=[2019, 2020], columns=['Price'])`
`df_out = pd.DataFrame([[71.849998], [77.400002]], index=[2019, 2020], columns=['Price])`

Now I will create the matrix:
`df_matrix = pd.DataFrame(np.outer(df_in, df_out), df_in.index, df_out.index)`

The output I get is:

```html
<style type="text/css">
    table.tableizer-table {
        font-size: 12px;
        border: 1px solid #CCC; 
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    } 
    .tableizer-table td {
        padding: 4px;
        margin: 3px;
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
    }
    .tableizer-table th {
        background-color: #104E8B; 
        color: #FFF;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
<table class="tableizer-table">
<thead><tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th></th><th>2019</th><th>2020</th></tr></thead><tbody>
 <tr><td>2019</td><td>5552.567794</td><td>5755.184768</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2020</td><td>5981.472023</td><td>6199.740004</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

It is multiplying instead of dividing. The next problem I am facing is that if

df_in.index > df_out.index

then value should be 0.

The result that I would like to see is:

```html
<style type="text/css">
    table.tableizer-table {
        font-size: 12px;
        border: 1px solid #CCC; 
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    } 
    .tableizer-table td {
        padding: 4px;
        margin: 3px;
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
    }
    .tableizer-table th {
        background-color: #104E8B; 
        color: #FFF;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
<table class="tableizer-table">
<thead><tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th></th><th>2019</th><th>2020</th></tr></thead><tbody>
 <tr><td>2019</td><td>1,075574</td><td>1,114822</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2020</td><td>0</td><td>1,034883</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

So thanks to all for your advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `divide.outer`:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.divide.outer(df_in,df_out)[:,0,:,0], df_in.index, df_out.index)
```

Output:

```
          2019      2020
2019  1.075574  0.998450
2020  1.114823  1.034884
```

Comment: Perfect, thx a lot. Do u have a an idea, that it dosnt divide if y > x, so that 1.114823  is N/A or 0?

Comment: look at `np.triu`.